# shared pointer used as a value - error during assignment

Tags: c++, boost

I have a sharepointer defined like this

```
typedef share_ptr<boost::unordered_map<int,string>> T;
boost::unordered_map<int,T> webData;

...
webData[100]=T(new boost::unordered_map<int,string>(make_pair(100,"json data returned")));
```

I always get error at this `webData` line `no instance of boost::unordered_map<K,T,H,P,A>....matches the argument list`

Comment: do you mean `std::shared_ptr`? or something else?

Comment: `make_pair(100, "bla")` will give `pair<int, char const *>`. Anyway, I don't think `unordered_map` allows passing an element to its constructor. Try doing this: `webData[100] = make_shared<T::element_type>(); (*webData[100])[100] = "json data returned";` ?

Answer (score 0):

[boost::unordered_map](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html) has no constructor which accepts an std::pair instance as a parameter. To get rid of the error, one has to write something like

```
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <string>

typedef boost::shared_ptr<boost::unordered_map<int, std::string> > T;

int main() {
    boost::unordered_map<int, T> webData;
    webData[100] = T(new boost::unordered_map<int, std::string>());
    webData[100]->insert(std::make_pair(100, "json data returned"));
    return 0;
}
```

The same code on coliru is [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f39f47e60d6e1fb3).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the explanations already given, you could use uniform initialization and `emplace` to cut back on some of the verbosity:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb0a9410b9ce286d)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <string>

typedef boost::shared_ptr<boost::unordered_map<int, std::string> > T;

int main() {
    boost::unordered_map<int, T> webData;
    webData[100] = T(new T::element_type { { 100, "json data returned" } });
    webData[100]->emplace(200, "more json");
}
```